# How to prove this integral is convergent

Tags: integration, analysis, improper-integrals

The integral is  $$\begin{align*}
I= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt[]{ (1-x^{2})(1-k^{2}x^{2}) }} \ dx
\end{align*}$$ with $0<k<1$ . $x=1$ is a singular point of the integrand. I want to show this integral is convergent.

My attempt was  $$\begin{align*}
I = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt[]{ (1+x)(1-x)(1+kx)(1-kx) }} \ dx \leq \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt[]{ (1-x)(1-kx) }} \ dx
\end{align*}$$ Since $1+x, 1+kx$ are greater than one

Then I don't know how to approach this. I tried to use $$\begin{align*}
\sqrt[]{ ab } \geq \frac{2}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}}
\end{align*}$$ but it doesn't work. I also tried the change of variable, but I failed.

Thus, without computing this integral, how should I show this integral is convergent? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like a candidate for a partial fraction in $x^2$...  Something like $\frac A{1-k^2x^2}-\frac B{1-x^2}$.

Comment: Notice that $1-kx\geq 1-k$ for $x\in[0,1]$, hence $I\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k}}\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x}}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $(1-k^2 x^2)^{-1/2}$ is bounded in view of $k<1$, so your integral is bounded by a constant times the integral of $(1-x^2)^{-1/2}$, which you can compute explicitly (its antiderivative is $\arcsin x$).